# How can I use c# attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I have to create a pdf report from several classes that are going to contains several properties.
I need to display the value of the propertie and a label in front of it.

Something like :

> detailsCalcul :
>   Numero client : valueOfMyProperty.

...

I was thinking of doing something like this :

```
[NomRapport("detailsCalcul")]
public class MyClass
{
    [NomChamp("Numero client")]
    public string NumeroClient { get; set; }
}
```

I sucessfully acessed to the value of my two attributes :

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] proprietes = typeof(MyClass).GetMembers();
MyClass client = new MyClass();
client.NumeroClient = "1234";
        foreach (var p in proprietes)
        {
            var aa = p.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < aa.Length; i++)
            {
                var test = aa[i];
                if (test.GetType() == typeof(NomChampAttribute))
                { 
                  var nomChamp = ((NomChampAttribute)attributes[i]).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

i would like to know if it is possible access to the value of my property while I am acessing to the attribute ?

Thanks for your help,

Guillaume

Comment: you have access to the property through the variable p? what do you want to do?. Further there's an overload to GetCustomAttributes that take a type use that and you won't have need to filter yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attribute does not know the context to which it is applied; you cannot even get to the property, let alone the instance. However, if you *have* a PropertyInfo and an instance, then:

```
object value = property.GetValue(instance, null);
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I wanted !